# How to I fix my deserialize error?

Tags: vb.net

**Why, hello everyone!**

I've got this program i've been working on for months. Basic back story of it is, its supposed to be able to transport and install applications for windows in the background, like iCloud does for apps!

Anywho, i'm using a serialize/deserialize method to save the properties (eg admin username and passwordhash, directories, ports, etc.).

I have a class called '**PropertyNest**' representing the properties and links to memory allocations. I'll cut it down to only the parts that the XMLSerializer looks at and saves.

```
Public Class PropertyNest
    'Huge bunch of functions that we dont need to look at

    '#######################

    Public  _wasLoadedFromFile As Boolean = False
    Private _port As Integer = 201
    Private _httpPort As Integer = 202
    Private _rootFolder As String = "\appstreamRoot"
    Private _adminUser As String = "Admin"
    Private _adminPass As String = "21232F297A57A5A743894A0E4A801FC3" 'admin
    Private _appstreamServerType As appStreamServerType = appStreamServerType.http
    Private _useDES3forserver As Boolean = True
    Private _encDES3pswd As String = "21232F297A57A5A743894A0E4A801FC3" 'admin

    'Properties and descriptors for 'PropertyGrid' object go here \|/
    '=================================================================

End Class
```

And its declared in the main window, **serverMain** like this,

```
Public Shared Property_Nest As AdvancedSettings.PropertyNest
```

and initialized later in like this,

```
    If settingsfilename = "" Then
        Property_Nest = New AdvancedSettings.PropertyNest()
    Else
        If propFileEncrypted = False Then
            WriteLog("From unprotected file...", False)
            Try
                Property_Nest = AdvancedSettings.PropertyNest.LoadFrom(settingsfilename)
            Catch ex As Exception
                WriteLog("FAILED! Making default property nest...")
                Property_Nest = New AdvancedSettings.PropertyNest()
            End Try
        Else
            WriteLog("From encrypted file...", False)
            Try
                Property_Nest = AdvancedSettings.PropertyNest.LoadFrom(settingsfilename, True, propFilePswd)
            Catch ex As Exception
                WriteLog("FAILED! Making default property nest...", False)
                Property_Nest = New AdvancedSettings.PropertyNest()
            End Try

        End If
    End If
```

Thats all well and good. Loading it from the file that its saved to is the problem. Inside the PropertyNest class, I have 2 serializers programmed like so:
(Sorry its a bunch, there's optional encrypting of the serialized products with TrippleDES)

```
    Public Sub SaveAs(ByVal filename As String, Optional ByVal Encrypted As Boolean = False)
        Dim extra As String
        If Encrypted = True Then : extra = "Encrypted? : Yes." : Else : extra = "Encrypted? : No."
        End If
        If filename = Nothing Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        writeLog2("Saving Property Nest to: " & filename & vbCrLf & extra, False)

        If Encrypted = False Then
            Dim writer As New Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(PropertyNest))
            Dim file As New System.IO.StreamWriter(filename)
            writer.Serialize(file, Me)
            file.Close()
        Else
            Dim writer As New Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(PropertyNest))
            Dim memstream As New System.IO.MemoryStream
            writer.Serialize(memstream, Me)
            memstream.Seek(0, IO.SeekOrigin.Begin)
            Dim file As New System.IO.StreamWriter(filename)
            Dim memstreamReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(memstream)
            Do
                file.WriteLine(serverMain.admin_des3Manager.Encrypt(memstreamReader.ReadLine()))
            Loop Until memstreamReader.EndOfStream = True
            file.Close()
        End If
        writeLog2("OK!")
    End Sub


    Shared Function LoadFrom(ByVal filename As String, Optional ByVal EncryptedWithPswd As Boolean = False, Optional ByVal Password As String = "") As PropertyNest
        Dim reader As New Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(PropertyNest))
        Dim file As New System.IO.StreamReader(filename)
        Dim newPropNest As PropertyNest
        If EncryptedWithPswd = False Then
            newPropNest = reader.Deserialize(file) 'Error in XML Document(11, 3)
        Else
            If Password = "" Then
                Dim convertedStream As New System.IO.MemoryStream
                Dim convertedWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(convertedStream)
                Do
                    convertedWriter.WriteLine(serverMain.admin_des3Manager.Decrypt(file.ReadLine()))
                Loop Until file.EndOfStream = True
                convertedWriter.Close()
                newPropNest = reader.Deserialize(convertedStream)
            Else
                Dim tempDES3 As New DES3(Password)
                Dim convertedStream As New System.IO.MemoryStream
                Dim convertedWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(convertedStream)
                Do
                    convertedWriter.WriteLine(tempDES3.Decrypt(file.ReadLine()))
                Loop Until file.EndOfStream = True
                convertedWriter.Close()
                newPropNest = reader.Deserialize(convertedStream)
            End If
        End If
        Return newPropNest
    End Function
```

I marked the error in there.

Phew. Almost done.

i'm only worried about unencrypted right now, so i did my duty to save a custom, non default property nest, and it wrote to the file like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <PropertyNest xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <_wasLoadedFromFile>false</_wasLoadedFromFile>
    <ServerPort>2010</ServerPort>
    <AdminUser>Matthew</AdminUser>
    <AdminPasswordHash>21232F297A57A5A743894A0E4A801FC3</AdminPasswordHash>
    <AppStreamPort>2020</AppStreamPort>
    <AppStream_ServerRoot>\appstreamRoot</AppStream_ServerRoot>
    <UseDES3>true</UseDES3>
    <EncDES3Pswd>21232F297A57A5A743894A0E4A801FC3</EncDES3Pswd>
</PropertyNest>
```

Awesome! now.... If you look at the '**LoadFrom**' function, you'll see i commented the line where i get the error... I dont see an error at 11, 3. Please help!

Thanks so much :D

Comment: As @saj said in his (C#!) answer, you need to make the properties of the `PropertyNest` public and writeable, in order for the deserialised XML to be written to the object.

Comment: post your code for the public properties for the PropertyNest class, and the appStreamServerType enum so i can compile it (stripping out the encryption part of the load).

Answer (score 0):

Your XML is valid, however the class you need to deserialise, should be like this according to visual studio, copy you XML to the clipboard, go to the edit menu, paste special and past XML as classes give you this, give it a try see if it works, you can use a c# to vb converter to change to VB if you need to.

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class PropertyNest
{

    private bool _wasLoadedFromFileField;

    private ushort serverPortField;

    private string adminUserField;

    private string adminPasswordHashField;

    private ushort appStreamPortField;

    private string appStream_ServerRootField;

    private bool useDES3Field;

    private string encDES3PswdField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public bool _wasLoadedFromFile
    {
        get
        {
            return this._wasLoadedFromFileField;
        }
        set
        {
            this._wasLoadedFromFileField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public ushort ServerPort
    {
        get
        {
            return this.serverPortField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.serverPortField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string AdminUser
    {
        get
        {
            return this.adminUserField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.adminUserField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string AdminPasswordHash
    {
        get
        {
            return this.adminPasswordHashField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.adminPasswordHashField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public ushort AppStreamPort
    {
        get
        {
            return this.appStreamPortField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.appStreamPortField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string AppStream_ServerRoot
    {
        get
        {
            return this.appStream_ServerRootField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.appStream_ServerRootField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public bool UseDES3
    {
        get
        {
            return this.useDES3Field;
        }
        set
        {
            this.useDES3Field = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string EncDES3Pswd
    {
        get
        {
            return this.encDES3PswdField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.encDES3PswdField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The properties are indeed public, i didnt include them because they only are Get/Sets directly back to those declarations.